# sql select sum with condition 2 tables?

Tags: sql

I have 2 table

```
Table Connection
----------------------------------------
|  ID       |  Member_ID  |  Connection| 
----------------------------------------
|  1        |  100        |  22        | 
----------------------------------------
|  2        |  101        |  15        | 
----------------------------------------
|  3        |  102        |  19        | 
----------------------------------------
|  4        |  103        |  21        | 

Table Member
---------------------------
|  ID         |  Status     |
---------------------------
|  100        |  0          | 
----------------------------
|  101        |  1          | 
----------------------------
|  102        |  1          | 
---------------------------
|  103        |  0          |
```

I want to get sum of Connection has `status =1`.
The result in example should be `15+19 = 34`.

Comment: `select sum(connection) from connection where ((select id from member where status=1) = connection.member_id)`. But it show error: `single-row subquery returns more than one row`

Comment: Post that in your question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to write this query using generic SQL:

```
SELECT
    SUM(Connection.Connection) AS ConnectionSum
FROM
    Connection
JOIN
    Member ON Connection.Member_ID = Member.ID
WHERE
    Member.Status = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine for you :

```
select sum(Connection) as Total_connection 
        from Connection where ID in 
( select ID from member where status = 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is in reference to MySQL and MariaDB databases:

```
SELECT SUM(Connection) 
       FROM Connection 
       WHERE Member_ID = ALL (SELECT ID FROM Member WHERE Status = 1);
```

OR

```
SELECT SUM(Connection) 
       FROM Connection 
       WHERE Member_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Member WHERE Status = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT SUM(cn.`connection`) sumresult FROM `connection`  AS cn WHERE cn.`member_id`
IN (SELECT em.id FROM `member` AS em WHERE em.`status`=1);

I hope it can help you as your require

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because the subquery returns more than one ID(multiple records) where as an equal operator can take only one value. Use an **IN** operator instead of Equal operator and your error will be removed.

```
select sum(connection) from connection 
where connection.member_id IN (select id from member where status=1)
```